# Jquery.i18n not working when using a path of a json file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

[image: index.html]

When i use jquery i18n plugin by giving the path of a json file its not working, it is printing the data-i18n value instead.

[image: This is working]

when i give the object here its  working as i want.

I want to use the path method instead of writing the key-value pairs of translation objects inside html file

Comment: Please don't include code as picture but prefer copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.i18n().load({
        'en': 'assets/i18n/en.json',
        'ar': 'assets/i18n/ar.json',
    }).done(function () {
        $('body').i18n();
    });
```

This made the code work.
I think the translation should only take place after the json file is loaded.

The script is going to traverse all elements inside body and replace their contents with the messages under the provided translation keys. If the key cannot be found, the initial content will be displayed as a fallback. -- [source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-choose-a-library-for-translating-your-javascript-apps-10f68de6a1d1/) -